# How to Highlight integer value in Bold style in VBA mailing Programming

Tags: vba, excel

Respected Experts, I just want to highlight integer value in Bold style in my below VBA mailing programming.

Please Find my Below Code:

```
    Dim FTD_Target As Integer

      FTD_Target = Round(Cells(49, 5), 2) ''--I want this value should be highlighted in Bold in .HTMLBody

    Dim rng As Range
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

     With OutMail
        .Display
        End With
            Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "mail id"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .HTMLBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "Please find the Daily Target:-" & 
FTD_Target

    End With
```

Please guide for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty solution:

```
    .HTMLBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "Please find the Daily Target:-" & "<b>" & 
FTD_Target & "</b>"
```

Best Solution:

```
 .HTMLBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "Please find the Daily Target:-" & "<div style='font-weight: bold;'>" & FTD_Target & "</div>"
```